# Is there a way to track setting component field a value always even if the valuer is not changed? Watcher is not appropriate

Tags: vue.js

I have a logger component that must show a message when one is set.

I tried watcher, but it works only when value changes. But component must to show all incoming values even double.

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
track:{
  message(){
    console.log(this.message)
  }
}
```

and in console appears

"message"

"message"

"new message"

"new message"

Comment: How do you set it? You could emit an event everytime you set value and somewhere in your component listen to it then log the message.

Comment: This is a way, but what if i have not access to place where it is set? There are no thing like i wrote in Vue?